# Can solutions of autonomous equations have a strict local maximum?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

For a function f(t) a strict local maximum at time t = a means f(a) is larger
than any nearby values of f(t). Graphically, it is at the top of a hill.

Question: Can solutions of autonomous equations have a strict local maximum?